# icCube: add calculated measure - average stock per date

Tags: average, iccube, iccube-reporting

I Have only one cube and several data tables. One of them named Stocks and have a next fields:

Date (mapped to Date dimension)
Company (mapped to Company dimension)
Product (mapped to Product dimension)
Amount
Money
Over it, i have [Measure].[Stock amount] as sum of Amount

Then, i need to add average stock per date as sum(amount) / count(distinct Date)

I have tried next options:
`CREATE CALCULATED MEMBER [Measures].[Stock average] AS 'sum([Measures].[Stock amount]) / DistinctCount ([Date].[Date].[Day])'`
or
`CREATE CALCULATED MEMBER [Measures].[Stock average] AS 'sum([Measures].[Stock amount]) / DistinctCount ([Rests].[Date])'`

both of them give strange wrong results in MDX IDE and give Error when i am trying to query them from Excel

Answer (score 2):

The solution pointed out by Oleksandr is fine however if you're using a lot the AverageOverDays I'd do thinks a bit different for simplicity and performance

1. Create a new measure that calculates the days distinct count. This can be done by adding a measure on the date column and using distinct count as fact aggregation method. Let's say it's [Measures].[Days With Data].

Using it is straight forward :

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AvgTrackCost] AS 
            [Measures].[Rests amount] / [Measures].[Days With Data]
```

This will work as expected in 100% of the scenarios, is faster and scales nicely.

Note that days without data do not count,, it's the same behavior as in Avg.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I can do it like this:

I have done it like this:

```
CREATE CALCULATED MEMBER [Measures].[Average rests] AS 
    AVG(
      EXISTING([Date].[Date].[Day].MEMBERS) ,
      [Measures].[Rests amount]
    )
```

To add in Cube

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AvgTrackCost] AS
  AVG( EXISTING([Date].[Date].[Day].MEMBERS), [Measures].[Rests amount] )
SELECT
  [Measures].[AvgTrackCost] on 0,
  [Distributors].[Distributors].Members ON 1
FROM
  [Spot2d]
```

To query in MDX Builder